# What to use for ancestry adjustment using eigenstrat

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm confused with the eigenstrat function. Do I use the output top k eigenvectors in succeeding regressions for ancestry adjustment? (since it is n x k) But the papers say the adjustment using 4 principal components (solving for this will make the matrices non-conformable - assuming I followed the input genofile where the rows are the p SNPs and the n subjects are the columns). Basically, I'm confused on the usage of eigenvector & principal components in papers and documentation. I think people use it interchangeably.

I tried following the documentation so I used the output eigenvectors in the succeeding regressions.

(basically what's on the documentation)

```
write.table(t(genotype), file = "riskalleles.txt", quote = FALSE, sep = "", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)

pca.eg <- eigenstrat(genoFile = "riskalleles.txt", outFile.Robj = "eigenstrat.result.list" outFile.txt = "riskalleles.result.txt", rm.marker.index = NULL,rm.subject.index = NULL, miss.val = 9, num.splits = 10,topK = NULL, signt.eigen.level = 0.01, signal.outlier = FALSE, iter.outlier = 5, sigma.thresh = 6)

ev <- pca.eg$topK.eigenvectors

gamma <- t(ev)%*%genotype

adjusted <- t(genotype - ev%*%gamma)
```

(solving for PCs using formula from my multivariate class)

```
pc <- t(genotype)%*%ev
```